# DotCover : Code coverage from commandline for an IIS Application

Tags: iis, dotcover

I am trying to analyse the code coverage of my **MVC application deployed on IIS**.

I am successfully able to analyse using the DotCover frontend as it has option for IIS Application.

But the problem is when I am trying to do it from command line. I need to know, what should my configuration file specify.

**A sample XML configuration file specifically for IIS Application**(Not IIS Express) would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to cover an IIS application via dotCover console runner. Please follow the ticket to be notified when this feature gets implemented: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-5921.

Answer (score 6):

This feature is now available since build 2018.1
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Remotely_Cover_a_Web_Application.html

To get coverage of a web application (IIS)
Make sure you have administrative privileges on the server.
Using the dotCover console runner, start coverage of the IIS service. For example:

`dotCover.exe cover-iis /Output=coverageReport.xml /Instance=1`

Here Instance is the ID of the current dotCover.exe instance. You will use this ID to send commands to this console runner.
In the covered application, go through the desired scenario or execute tests that do this.
Run the second console runner instance that sends the "get snapshot and kill process" command to the first running instance:

`dotCover.exe send /Command=GetSnapshotAndKillChildren /Instance=1`

Here Instance is the ID of the first dotCover.exe instance you have specified in step 2.
After you send the command, the IIS service and dotCover.exe instances will be stopped and the coverage snapshot will be saved.

Comment: Please include the relevant info in your answer.

Comment: This covers everything IIS is running? If so, is it possible to cover only a single web app?

Comment: @grae22 or for anyone still wondering - you can use other arguments (like `--Filters`) on dotCover to scope coverage down to given modules, classes, and functions: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html#